# Plotly equivalent for pd.DataFrame.hist

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

I am looking for a way to imitate the `hist` method of `pandas.DataFrame` using plotly. Here's an example using the `hist` method:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load example data set
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# plot distributions of all continuous variables
iris.drop('species',inplace=True,axis=1)
iris.hist()
plt.tight_layout()
```

which produces:

[image]

How would one do this using plotly?

**EDIT:**

I am looking for a method where the user doesn't explicitly has to define the number of rows and columns and where the output plot should be as 'square-like' as possible. `pd.DataFrame.hist` by default will create square-like plots when not being provided with a particular number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can make subplots using plotly's make_subplots() function. From there you add traces with the desired data and position within the subplot.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(x=iris['petal_length']),
    row=1, col=1
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(x=iris['petal_width']),
    row=1, col=2
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(x=iris['sepal_length']),
    row=2, col=1
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(x=iris['sepal_width']),
    row=2, col=2
)
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLHeu.png)

Comment: Is there also a more automated way of doing this where one does not have to define the rows and columns and the respective indices and where the number of variables is unknown?

Answer (score 2):

You can melt the dataframe and then use facet_col to get individual sub-plots for each column.

First, set plotly as the backend plotting tool for Pandas:

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
```

Now we can melt and plot the data simultaneously. When we melt the data, we compress the dataframe into 2 columns, 'variable' and 'value' where 'variable' is the name of the column that the corresponding value comes from:

```
df.melt().plot(kind='hist', facet_col = 'variable')
```

Finally, you can tweak the subplots using the facet_col_wrap and facet_col_spacing arguments:

```
 df.melt().plot(kind='hist', facet_col = 'variable', facet_col_wrap = 4, facet_col_spacing = 0.6)
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, but in contrast to the matplotlib backend it will easily fail when you have a lot of variables (118 in my case). It will only work when I set `facet_col_spacing = 0` but then I am left with a gibberish looking plot.

Comment: Have you tried making the plot bigger using the 'width' and 'height' arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Plotly has a histogram function built in so all you have to do is write

```
px.histogram()
```

and pass the data column and x=label, and it should work. Here's a link to the documentation https://plotly.com/python/histograms/

Comment: I already tried `plotly.express.histogram(iris)` but this places the histograms on top of each other.